# What is the status of ESA's proposed human mission to the Moon?

Tags: the-moon, reference-request, crewed-spaceflight, esa

As part of the [Aurora Exploration Programme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurora_programme#Timeline), there is a proposed human mission to the Moon in 2024. The astronaut capsule would be launched atop an Ariane 5 rocket.

What is the status of this mission? Is it going to take place? Are they on time? What components have been completed so far?

Comment: Yeah [this presentation](http://www.hou.usra.edu/meetings/leag2014/presentations/carpenter.pdf) is the latest (actually presented less than an hour ago at the [LEAG meeting](http://www.hou.usra.edu/meetings/leag2015/)). Let me know in our [chat] if you'll require password to access the document or the meeting itself. Also see some related [LEAG meeting proceedings papers](http://www.hou.usra.edu/meetings/leag2015/downloadable_program.pdf) (PDF) and [LEAG Analysis Reports](http://www.lpi.usra.edu/leag/reports.shtml). Some more info can be found at [ILEWG](http://sci.esa.int/ilewg/), too.

Answer (score 6):

I asked Jim Carpenter, lead scientist for ESA on the [Luna 27 lander](http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-34504067) project, about this. He said that although the plans and protocols for Aurora are still in place, it is currently on hold, outside of the [Exomars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExoMars) program.

ESA announced the [Heracles](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Human_Spaceflight/ESA_Moon_challenge) program a few weeks ago. The winners of that competition will present their plans at the [Moon 2020-2030](http://spaceflight.esa.int/humanrobotics/about/) symposium in December.

[image: infrastructure system for lunar exploration]

The subtitle of the symposium is 'A New Era of Human and Robotic Exploration'. 
ESA's position on human exploration of the Moon is summed up in one of the slides from [last year's LEAG meeting](http://www.hou.usra.edu/meetings/leag2014/presentations/carpenter.pdf):

[image: ESA position on human exploration of the Moon]